# Solr Admin Query doesn't show all the attributes available in the collection schema

Tags: indexing, solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I have a solr 8.4.1 collection that has the attributes like below -

[image]

But when I run a query against that collection, it brings back just very few attributes as shown below. I have run this query for 10000s of records also, passing in * in the fl value, but it never shows the other attributes for any of the records in the collection.

[image]

Would be grateful if someone can give me some idea as to why most of the attributes getting dropped while the query is run, even though the schema contains those attributes and some of it should be populated as well.

NOTE: Most of the fields that are not getting retrieved have the field type - `org.apache.solr.schema.TextField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text fields are sometimes indexed (so you can search the values inside them) but not stored. When they are not stored you cannot retrieve their values in a query, which looks a lot like what's going on here.

You can check the specifics of the fields in question in the Schema screen. For an stored field you should see something like this:

[image]

whereas for a not-stored field you'll notice that "stored" column is missing:

[image]

Comment: Hello Hector, Thanks for the guidance. This seems to be the case here. When I see those fields, which I am not able to retrieve, they do not show as being stored. So is there a way to see what the contents are for those unstored fields or is it that we can just use them in searching, but cannot see their contents? Thanks again for your guidance

Comment: If the field is not stored you can only use it for searching. You could create a separate field that is a text field and mark it as "stored", reindex your data, and then you'll be able to see them.

Comment: Technically you can peek at these *not stored* fields if you use them in your facets, but notice that you'll see the tokens of these field, not their entire values.